# What is wrong with the logic in this sequence?

Tags: python, logic

I am a Python beginner, and I decided that I wanted to create a program over my summer holiday, before I did this however I decided I would make a small program before, to practice creating GUI's.  I am working on a joke machine, that uses the random module to select a random integer that will decide which joke is displayed, however it seems to only ever output joke 3, regardless of how many times I run it.

I can't see any issues here, any advice?

```
joke_select = random.randint (1,3)

joke1 = "Why do you never see elephants hiding in trees?\n because they're really good at it!"
joke2 = "What is grey and can't climb a tree? \n A parking lot"
joke3 = "What is red and bad for your teeth?\n A brick"

if joke_select == '1':
    joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke1)
elif joke_select == '2':
    joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke2)
else:
    joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke3)

def get_joke():
    joke_label.pack ()
```

Comment: `joke_select` is of type `int` but you compare it to a `string`, so it is always the `else` which is reased.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the value of `joke_select` before you do the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if joke_select == '1':
```

`joke_select` is only ever an integer, but you're comparing it to a string here. Try comparing to an integer instead.

```
if joke_select == 1:
```

Likewise for `elif joke_select == '2':`.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts looks for a string and you generate a number.

```
if joke_select == 1:
    joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke1)
elif joke_select == 2:
    joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke2)
else:
   joke_label = tkinter.Label (main, text = joke3)
```

will probably work

Answer (score 0):

Just a piece of advice: there is no need for whitespace on such things as `random.randint (1,3)`. It would be clearer to have this as `random.randint(1,3)`. There are a few more places in your code where this also applies.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, is there any particular reason to avoid space or is it just standard to not use it?

Comment: No problem! Whitespace immediately before the open parenthesis that starts the argument list of a function call just makes it a little less clear that what is inside the brackets is the argument list of that function call. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) for more detail. It is also just not conventional to add whitespace here, and so it may cause a little confusion for other people reading your code.

Comment: Ah I see, I suppose in the long run I will get used to not doing it, I see now how it makes things clearer to read, I just found when actually programming it looked more spaced to me, which seemed to help me for some reason.

Comment: Well if it works for you, for small programs there is no harm in keeping the whitespace while coding, and then maybe refactoring the code before showing it to someone else. This may be a bit tedious for larger projects though, so yes, it would definitely be good to get into the habit of following a style guide like pep-8 or something similar. Anyway, best of luck in learning Python!